# Can I use Javax imports in a JavaFX program?

Tags: javafx, javax

I'm coding a JavaFX program GUI program. I need to find the length of audio files and I need to use a 'Javax' import for that. (It seems I can achieve that using 'media' import in JavaFX. But I'm struggling to figure out how to). I understand that it's best not to mix Java Swing and JavaFX. But can I use 'Javax' imports in a JavaFX program?

Comment: Your ***Java***FX program is written in Java so of course it's possible to import classes from the `javax` classes/packages. If this is a good idea is a different question...

Comment: @fabian, Sorry I should have been more clear with my question. I found out that I could import it. But I wasn't sure if it's good or not. I didn't want there to be any bugs or something because of this. That's what I meant to ask. Would you advice against importing Javax in a JavaFX program?